# SFML: Draw Polygons with List of Vertices

Tags: c++, polygon, sfml

I'm trying to figure out how to draw polygons with crinkled edges in SFML. I've tried a couple of things, including LineStrip, TriangleStrip, and just Triangles. I've been able to get a couple of different results, but none were the on I was looking for.

The Best result I have gotten is through LineStrip, which consistenty creates the Shape I am trying to build:

```cpp
sf::VertexArray T(sf::LineStrip, 6);
        
T[0] = sf::Vector2f(10.f, 20.f);        
T[1] = sf::Vector2f(110.f, 20.f);
T[2] = sf::Vector2f(110.f, 120.f);
T[3] = sf::Vector2f(10.f, 120.f);
T[4] = sf::Vector2f(80.f, 80.f);
T[5] = sf::Vector2f(10.f, 20.f);
```

[image]

However, as you can tell, the shape is not filled.
I also messed around with TriangleStrip, which looked like it would give me the desired result from the documentation:

[image]

Using the same code(Substituting LineStrip for TriangleStrip), however, caused a shape that lacked the crease I was looking for:

[image]

This is the same shape but with the Vertices colorfilled to help highlight things, for some added info.
[image]

Other results from messing around with TriangleStrip yielded a few different results, however none of which were the one I needed. These results included one where the line went to the center and then to the end point, and one where it drew the creased area but closed it in, creating a weird carve. I also tried using Triangle, but that was inconsistent and didn't even get close to what I needed.

Does anyone know how to get a filled crinkly polygon?

Comment: If you want to use a triangle strip, you need to drop `T[5]` and move the current `T[4]` between `T[1]` and `T[2]`. It just looks like you haven't understood how each primitive uses the points and in which order.

Answer (score -1):

[Triangulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation) the polygon and render the resulting triangle list with `sf::Triangles`.

Comment: Ah, so I should be using a list of triangles for rendering instead of one VertexArray? Thats interesting. I presume there is no way to quick Triangulate a poly in c++/SFML or is there?